# how to display checkbox input in table with phtml and css?

Tags: php, html, css

I have a table where I need to put a checkbox input but when I do it, It's not align
[As you can see in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYtFE.png)

```
<table >
    <tr>
        <td style="border:#000 1px solid;">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <label >labeL1</label>
        </td>
        <td style="border:#000 1px solid;">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <label >labeL2</label>
        </td>
        <td style="border:#000 1px solid;">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <label >labeL3</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

There is any way to align the checkbox with label other than "position:fixed" ?

Comment: do not use tables for layout. Tables are for data display only. Use divs instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   .checkbox input {
     vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .checkbox label span {
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
```